# HFS filesystem presents itself empty

Tags: filesystem

Today I was confronted with an Ubuntu 20.04 virtualbox VM that failed to boot. Somehow the OS-diskimage seems lost. A second vdi-image was mounted and seems to be HFS.
But mounting that filesystem (30G) only shows me an empty directory.

fsck.hfs gives a coredump

running `strings` on the diskdevice shows a lot of content recognizable as files/dirs of the filesystem.

Any tips to get this going again would be very welcome

Comment: I would explore for issues on your *unstated* HOST OS

Comment: I've created a new VM, added the 30G vdi and expected to be able to mount that filesystem. It is currently more important to recover that filesystem than to get the original VM going again